# Ajax call to move files in sling

Tags: jquery, ajax, jcr, jackrabbit, sling

I need to make an ajax call to move the files from one folder to another in sling repository.
I am able to delete files via this ajax call

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url : del_url,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", make_base_auth());
            },
            type : "POST",
            traditional : "false" ,
            data:{
                ":operation" : "delete",
                ":applyTo" :files

            }

        });
```

I now require to move files from 'copyFromURL' to 'moveToURL'. How can I do that with ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your specific Ajax call, but there is [move support in the Sling Post Servlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#movefrom). Here is how this would work for a HTML form:

```
<!-- trailing slash generates a name for the new node -->
<form method="POST" action="/content/page/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="image@MoveFrom" value="/tmp/upload/123" />
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Rahul - if this answer has helped you find a solution please remember to upvote it and/or mark it as accepted, so that others know that this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by this ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: src_url,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth());
    },
    type: "POST",
    traditional: "false",
    data: {
        ":operation": "move",
        ":dest": dest_url + "/",
        ":applyTo": files
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error:' + textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("files successfully moved");
    }

});
```